# Different output from code used in function and used alone in R

Tags: r, function, subset

I've been working with this kind of data to evaluate some stocks for my diploma thesis

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("NOK",from="2012-01-01")
data<-NOK
p1<-4 
dC<-data[,4]
dO<-data[,1]
emaC<-EMA(dC,n=p1)
w1<-1.1
Profit_L_1<-((lag(dC,-1)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_2<-((lag(dC,-2)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_3<-((lag(dC,-3)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_4<-((lag(dC,-4)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_5<-((lag(dC,-5)-lag(dO,-1))/(lag(dO,-1)))*100
Profit_L_all<-ifelse(Profit_L_1>w1,Profit_L_1,
                     ifelse(Profit_L_2>w1,Profit_L_2,
                            ifelse(Profit_L_3>w1,Profit_L_3,
                                   ifelse(Profit_L_4>w1,Profit_L_4,
                                          ifelse(Profit_L_5>w1,Profit_L_5,Profit_L_5)))))
ChoosedN<-ifelse(Profit_L_all==Profit_L_1,1,
                 ifelse(Profit_L_all==Profit_L_2,2,
                        ifelse(Profit_L_all==Profit_L_3,3,
                               ifelse(Profit_L_all==Profit_L_4,4,
                                      ifelse(Profit_L_all==Profit_L_5,5,0)))))

Profit_day<-Profit_L_all/ChoosedN
Winloss<-ifelse(Profit_day>0.3,1,
                ifelse(Profit_day<=0.3,0,"nothing"))
Pos_emaC_dC_D<-emaC<dC
Pos_emaC_dC_UP<-emaC>dC
frame<-data.frame(Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Profit_L_all,ChoosedN,Profit_day,Winloss)
colnames(frame)<-c("Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Profit_L_all","ChoosedN","Profit_day","Winloss")
frame<-frame[complete.cases(frame),]
```

Output of it is the data.frame called frame which I work with. It is clear without any NA's.

I have written this function to quick evaluate  combinations of variables in this frame

```
quickmycomb<-function (x,y){
  combination<-deparse(substitute(y))
  df<-subset(x,y)
  Success<-length(subset(df,Winloss==1)$Winloss)/length(df$Winloss)
  absnumber<-nrow(df)
  relnumber<-nrow(df)/nrow(frame)
  sl<-data.frame(Success,absnumber,relnumber)
  return(sl)
}
```

and when I use this function like

```
quickmycomb(frame,lag(Pos_emaC_dC_D,1) & Pos_emaC_dC_UP)
```

It says that the output is frame with 86 rows in this case

```
    Success absnumber relnumber
1 0.6162791        86 0.1396104
```

But when I use the code from this function 
subset(frame,"combination") with the same combination of variables like

```
subset(frame,lag(Pos_emaC_dC_D,1) & Pos_emaC_dC_UP)
```

It says that the output is data.frame with 0 rows!!! 
I don't understand it, I suppose that the right output is the second, but I don't know why it doesn't work in the function.
Any advices where should be the problem?

Comment: Don't use subset in a function. Just use normal indexing. The help page for subset even warns you about this.

Comment: And when you post code, make sure it's runnable. This code seems to be missing a definition for `dO`. Plus, since this question isn't about creating the data.frame, there's no need to post all that code. It would have been better to just `dput()` the data (or a subset) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick I am sorry for that, it is repaired. I did it because I thought it has to be reproducible this way. Thanks for comments

Comment: @Dason What indexing do you excatly mean? I need to have new frame and apply some functions on it. Like frame[frame$Pos_emaC_dC_UP=="TRUE" & lag(fram$Pos_emaC_dC_D=="TRUE",1),] ?

Comment: Get rid of your monstrous `ifelse` tarpit and use either `switch` or a `which` construction with your various values concatenated into a vector. Make all your `Profit_L_x` into a vector. And for goodness' sake don't repeat the `ifelse` -- you already know which value was selected!  Then at least we have a chance of seeing what is going on.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry for that, can you show me how exactly do you mean it by editing my question?

Comment: @Bury. Yes, the error must be reproducible but in this case that just has to do with your function. How you populate your data frame is just a big, distracting mess.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry for repeating question, but can You show me how excatly did you mean to vectorise the Profit_L_x, i.e. show how to transpose it in to the code? I am trying to optimize my another code a this is a problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `subset` with a variable for the condition because subset itself will use `substitute` to see what exactly was passed to the function. However, you can pass through values to subset. One fix is

```
quickmycomb.1 <- function (x,...) {
  df <- subset(x,...)
  Success <- length(subset(df,Winloss==1)$Winloss)/length(df$Winloss)
  absnumber <- nrow(df)
  relnumber <- nrow(df)/nrow(frame)
  sl <- data.frame(Success,absnumber,relnumber)
  return(sl)
}
```

Alternative you can process the subsetting yourself inside the function with

```
quickmycomb.2 <- function (x,y){
  combination <- eval(substitute(y), x, parent.frame())
  df <- x[combination, ]
  Success <- length(subset(df,Winloss==1)$Winloss)/length(df$Winloss)
  absnumber <- nrow(df)
  relnumber <- nrow(df)/nrow(frame)
  sl <- data.frame(Success,absnumber,relnumber)
  return(sl)
}
```

When you run them both

```
quickmycomb.1(frame,lag(Pos_emaC_dC_D,1) & Pos_emaC_dC_UP)
quickmycomb.2(frame,lag(Pos_emaC_dC_D,1) & Pos_emaC_dC_UP)
```

they will both produce

```
  Success absnumber relnumber
1     NaN         0         0
```

just as when you run it from the current environment.

Comment: Yeah, but I forgot to join the combination into sl data.frame where I wanted to see the combination which was used (Pos_emaC_dC_UP & ...) That was the reason to use it but in proccess of formulating question i forgot to join it in. And your solutions doesn't work with it.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying this solution doesn't work?

Comment: No, I say that I forgot the reason why I gave combination<- into function. The reason was to see, in final data.frame sl which combination was used in format how it was given to function quickmycomb(). And if I join the combination into sl data.frame it doesn't work. It was my mistake to forget it like I mentioned above.